# Why are Thunderbird-Lightning events not showing in Unity panel calendar?

Tags: thunderbird, indicator, lightning

This is very annoying as Evolution events were not only visible, but also clickable in the unity panel calendar. Isn't this possible with Thunderbird in Oneiric?

Comment: Okay it's 2013 and still my lightning events are not showing in the unity panel calendar. Has this issue now been resolved?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The calendar in the Unity panel is hard-coded to work with Evolution; however, progress is being made on fixing this.  See [this post on Mike Conley's Blog](http://mikeconley.ca/blog/2011/08/11/fiddling-with-an-eds-provider-for-lightning-calendar/).

In short, Lightening events in Thunderbird can be shown in the 'indicator-datetime' panel calendar, but the plugin is not finished or released yet.  (For example, clicking an event doesn't automatically open the event in Thunderbird)

Answer (score 5):

[EDS Calendar Integration](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/eds-calendar-integration) addon synchronizes Thunderbird with calendar indicator.

Note: I'm the author