# How do I integrate Lightning with the messaging menu?

Tags: unity, thunderbird, messaging-menu, lightning

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why are Thunderbird-Lightning events not showing in Unity panel calendar?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/64916/why-are-thunderbird-lightning-events-not-showing-in-unity-panel-calendar)

Is there any way to integrate the events on lightning calendar with the the unity calendar section?

Of course I would like to do this preferably without having to install evolution.

Thanks for your help.