# How to use the default calendar indicator more effectively in 13.04

Tags: 13.04, indicator, thunderbird, evolution, calendar

How to sync all my calendar events to the calendar indicator in ubuntu 13.04?

I have got a calendar indicator on my panel next to volume but it never shows any of my events.
I have got thunderbird installed and have synced my google calendar with it. 
Is that the default calendar in 13.04?

Comment: which desktop are you using? if Gnome, there is a solution in http://www.webupd8.org/2011/09/google-calendar-gnome-shell-integration.html

Comment: To get events on day-time indicator you need evolution.Since you are using thunderbird, sync evolution calendar with thunderbird using [evolution-mirror](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/evolution-mirror/) add-on.

Comment: I am using unity. And evolution is unninstalled

Comment: Install it using `sudo apt-get install evolution`

Comment: this answer helped me get the indicator show thunderbird lighning calendar events: http://askubuntu.com/a/564257/14747

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** This answer outlines how to use Thunderbird Lightning and synchronize that with your Ubuntu (11-14 so far!). Personally I prefer the interface for Thunderbird rather then evolution. I hope at least this helps you somewhat answer your question. At some point evolution-mirror stopped working for me.

## Install Thunderbird

1. Install Thunderbird on your machine
2. Go to Tools >> Add-ons and type "Lightning" in the search dialog
3. Then select the Available Add-ons option and install Lightning
4. Repeat the steps above but install "Automatic Export"

## Configure Thunderbird

1. Add a new Calendar (File >> New >> Calendar)

> For Facebook you need to find the iCal link on your facebook feed.

1. Add a WebCal calendar & make sure to check "Show reminders"
2. Paste in your Calendar feed
3. Repeat these steps for any other calendars that you want

## Export Calendars

This process allows us to properly export your feeds out from Thunderbird which will integrate into Ubuntu's top Calendar

1. Go to your Extensions and edit the preferences of the Automatic Export Add-on
2. Check off recurrent export and setup an output director your your files
3. Check off iCal export and which Calendars you wish to export

## Integrate into Ubuntu

> As it stands Ubuntu / Ubuntu Gnome only properly integrates with Evolution

1. Start Evolution
2. Select New > Calendar
3. Check "Use an existing iCalendar" and find one of the calendars you have export
4. Uncheck "Allow Evolution to update the file"
5. Repeat for all of your calendars
6. Select Edit >> Preferences
7. Click on the Reminders tab

> You can either choose to keep reminders on (which will be initiated by THunderbird automatically) or turn them off in this interface.
>
> Close evolution (you don't need to re-open it again since the Evolution service takes care of the synchronization)
>
> You're done! Now whenever you open Thunderbird you will receive reminders from Facebook, and can view all of your events by clicking on the Date/Time in the top menu.